# what compile must be change to implementation, I has been changed all

Tags: android, gradle, compilation, implementation, obsolete

I has been changed all of **compile** in gradle to be **implementation** . But there is still warning in my project. do you know what I left behind? thank you

[image: compile and implementation change in gradle]

Comment: In android studio press `Ctrl + Shift + F` and search for `compile` keyword. Check if you have missed at some place. If this doesn't help paste the code instead of image.

Comment: I have did that. (search) and there isn't compile cause I have replaced all of them. That why I ask like that.

Answer (score -1):

You have not left anything. The warning is just about the newer version of dependencies which are available and can be integrated into your project if you want.

And for "compile" related warning, just go to your gradle file and find "compile" keyword and then replace it with "implementation"

Comment: yes of course, I understand for that. But I have changed all of "compile" to "implementation" but that still there is warning about that. So, I think maybe there is some mistake in my declaration, or maybe not using "implementation" but "api" . Thank's for your help Anshul